# Build failure due to missing libraries

Tags: java, maven

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project spring-intergation: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] \spring-intergation\src\main\java\uk\co\dd\spring\domain\User.java:[3,24] package javax.persistence does not exist
[ERROR] \spring-intergation\src\main\java\uk\co\dd\spring\domain\User.java:[4,24] package javax.persistence does not exist
[ERROR] \spring-intergation\src\main\java\uk\co\dd\spring\domain\User.java:[5,24] package javax.persistence does not exist
[ERROR] \spring-intergation\src\main\java\uk\co\dd\spring\domain\User.java:[6,24] package javax.persistence does not exist
[ERROR] \spring-intergation\src\main\java\uk\co\dd\spring\domain\User.java:[7,24] package javax.persistence does not exist
[ERROR] \spring-intergation\src\main\java\uk\co\dd\spring\domain\User.java:[9,1] cannot find symbol
```

But i have added all the libraries in my eclipse by right clicking the project and adding the external jars.

When i try to run mvn compile i get these errors with a lot of other jars also missing.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>java</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>

        <configuration>
          <mainClass>uk.co.dd.spring.App</mainClass>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>uk.co.dd.spring</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-intergation</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>spring-intergation</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>



  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Should i do anything with POM.xml

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Add this to your dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
  <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>  
  <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: \spring-intergation\src\main\java\uk\co\vinoth\spring\web\UserController.java:[3,25] package javax.servlet.http does not exist
\spring-intergation\src\main\java\uk\co\vinoth\spring\web\UserController.java:[4,25] package javax.servlet.http does not exist
\spring-intergation\src\main\java\uk\co\vinoth\spring\web\UserController.java:[7,38] package org.springframework.web.servlet does not exist
\spring-intergation\src\main\java\uk\co\vinoth\spring\web\UserController.java:[8,54] package org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction does not exist

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of maven is that you describe all dependencies of your project in `pom.xml` rather than add them as jars in your IDE.

When you have dependencies configured in `pom.xml`, you can easily generate Eclipse project with the corresponding dependencies by running `mvn eclipse:eclipse`, or add them to the existing project with [m2eclipse](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/) plugin.