# mvn compile error using command line but succes with eclipse

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, docker, dockerfile

I have a maven project I would like to run on the docker. When I compile it with eclipse I get no errors. But when I do with docker and compile it manually I get lots of errors

this my Dockerfile

```
FROM maven:3.5-jdk-8 as BUILD
ENV MAVEN_HOME /usr/share/maven
ENV MAVEN_CONFIG "$USER_HOME_DIR/.m2"
# speed up Maven JVM a bit
ENV MAVEN_OPTS="-XX:+TieredCompilation -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1"
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/mvn"]
# copy json
RUN mkdir /root/firebase/
COPY /json/. /root/firebase/
COPY /configFile/. /root/.
COPY /Internal_Sele_SELE/pom.xml /usr/src/myapp/
# install dependecies
RUN mvn -f /usr/src/myapp/. verify clean --fail-never
RUN mvn -f /usr/src/myapp/ dependency:copy-dependencies
# copy source
ADD /Internal_Sele_SELE/. /usr/src/myapp/
WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp/
RUN rm -rf /json/ /configFile/
# compiling source
RUN mvn package

# for tomcat web server
FROM tomcat:9-jre8-alpine
RUN mkdir /root/firebase/
COPY /json/. /root/firebase/
COPY /configFile/. /root/.
COPY --from=BUILD /usr/src/myapp/target/MTWS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/MTWS.war
```

This error that I have been getting.
because the error obtained much of the same, i will give each one a different error

```
[ERROR] /usr/src/myapp/src/com/rsmurniteguh/webservice/dep/util/LanguageUtil.java:[15,28] unmappable character for encoding UTF8
[ERROR] /usr/src/myapp/src/com/rsmurniteguh/webservice/dep/kthis/model/Visitvitalsignrecord.java:[4,1] package javax.persistence does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/src/myapp/src/com/rsmurniteguh/webservice/dep/kthis/model/Visitvitalsignrecord.java:[13,2] cannot find symbol
  symbol: class Entity
```

this makes me so stressed.
Anyone who could help me would be very helpful to me

This my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.rsmurniteguh.webservice.dep</groupId>
    <artifactId>MTWS</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself.-->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>
                                            org.apache.maven.plugins
                                        </groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            maven-compiler-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                            [3.3,)
                                        </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>compile</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore></ignore>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
          <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>  
          <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
            <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.0</version>
        </dependency> 

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>smtp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>

         <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
          <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-net/commons-net -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.warrenstrange</groupId>
          <artifactId>googleauth</artifactId>
          <version>0.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-jaxrs -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.7</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.fusesource.jansi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jansi</artifactId>
            <version>1.14</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: It's missing install Java in your rocker file

Comment: i try with install java buat it's return the same error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Build failure due to missing libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4500037/build-failure-due-to-missing-libraries)

Comment: @Adam still error with the different error ,
package org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool does not exist,
package oracle.jdbc does not exist,
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class DataSource,
  location: class ,
package oracle.net.aso does not exist

Comment: Have you provided the necessary dependencies?

Comment: already, is there a wrong way when I'm compiling or command less?
When I change the command ADD/Internal_Sele_SELE/. /usr/src/myapp/ be /Internal_Sele_SELE/*/usr/src/myapp/ADD-ON it's not return error but when i open localhost:8080/MTWS/ it's not display anything @Adam

Comment: First I would suggest to keep the convention over configuration and remove your configuration about `<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>` which makes life easier...furthermore I would suggest to fix your error related to the wrong encoding ....

Comment: hope you can help me! @khmarbaise