# mvn package fails with new SpringBoot project

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I just downloaded the default SpringBoot project with default settings from the [initilizizer](https://start.spring.io/):

Here's my codebase after several test codes:
I had no problem with rest api, thymeleaf but I failed with JPA.

Build fails:

```
package javax.persistance does not exist
cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol: class Entity
```

It failed just after adding entity annotation, nothing else:

I really like Java. **I can't tell you how I want to learn this language**...and I believe that I can be successful with the syntax, I can understand the tutorials. This is my only serious problem before moving forward.

My configuration:

```
Apache Maven 3.6.0 (97c98ec64a1fdfee7767ce5ffb20918da4f719f3; 2018-10-24T21:41:47+03:00)
Maven home: C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\maven\apache-maven-3.6.0\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_191, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program 
Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

IDE: Spring Tool Suite 4

Comment: `maven clean build` try that

Comment: Did you mean mvn clean install? Tried, no chance.

Comment: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4500037/build-failure-due-to-missing-libraries make sure that you have `javax.persistence` dep inherited.

Comment: You mispelled the import `javax.persistance.Entity;` it should be `import javax.persistence.Entity;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you import package manually ? It should be as below in your `User.java`

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
```